# add waiting message before load remote data in bootstrap modal box

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have this code for load remote php data into bootstrap modal box:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        if ($(this).width() < 400) {
            $('#tabs-content').removeClass('col-xs-10').addClass('col-xs-12')
        } else {
            $('#tabs-content').removeClass('col-xs-12').addClass('col-xs-10')
        }
    }).resize();
});
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('click', '.push', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'details.php', // in here you should put your query 
            data: {
                'bookid': id,
                'lang': 'fa',
                'csrf_token': 'MTQ0OTQxNDQ0MUVvN2JwNXNJRHVxMDZmOXFpQm1ROFNNTk1UZ3lPMGZO'
            }, 
            success: function(r) {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
                $('#bookdetails').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    }) // put your modal id 
                $('.something').show().html(r);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

This worked for me But I need to show loading `message/image` before load data.

How do add waiting message/icon?!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to show `image/message` before `Ajax call` and hide it in `success: function(r)`

Assuming you have image which to show before modal load, image HTML e.g

```
<img class="progress" src="http://downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif" style="display:none;">
```

and in JS, just show image with `.show()` function and after modal load in `success: function(r)` hide is with `.hide()` function

```
$(document).on('click', '.push', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".progress").show(); // <-- Show progress image
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'details.php', // in here you should put your query 
        data: {
            'bookid': id,
            'lang': 'fa',
            'csrf_token': 'MTQ0OTQxNDQ0MUVvN2JwNXNJRHVxMDZmOXFpQm1ROFNNTk1UZ3lPMGZO'
        }, 
        success: function(r) {
            // now you can show output in your modal 
            $('#bookdetails').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                }) // put your modal id 
            $('.something').show().html(r);
            $(".progress").hide(); // <-- Hide progress image
        }
    });
});
```

[Minimal example with delay and fade](http://jsfiddle.net/20b7q67k/1/)